# Dream-perturbing doubts with my drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I tried to do a dropdown menu, but I have a lot of questions and it seems I am doing all wrong. Some of the major question that are perturbing my dreams are:

- Should I use `list-style:none;` on ULs or LIs (or both)?
- Is it better to put `background-color` and `border` on As or LIs?
- Should the LIs that are inside the absolute floating UL have
  `float:left;` or `position:relative;`?

The code I am using seems of work, but my biggest fear is that I am writing unnecessary lines or even bad coding.

Please help.

**The CSS I am using:**

```
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#menu{
margin:0 auto;
width:800px;
background:#999;
border:1px solid #777;
}

#menu ul{
list-style:none;
border-right:1px solid #aeaeae;
/*Not sure about this V*/
position:relative;
float:left;
}

#menu li ul{
font-weight:normal;
display:none;
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #777;
width:200px;
/*Not sure about this V*/
float:none;
margin-left:-2px;
}

#menu li{
display:block;
position:relative;
float:left;
background:#999;
border-right:1px solid #777;
border-left:1px solid #aeaeae;
}

#menu li li{
float:none;
background:#eaeaea;
border:0;
border-top:1px solid #666;
}

#menu li:hover{
background:#a6a6a6;
}

#menu li li:hover{
background:#f5f5f5;
}

#menu a{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
padding:5px 15px;
}

#menu li ul a{
color:#333;
}

#menu a:hover{
color:#fff;
}

#menu li ul a:hover{
color:red;
}

#menu li li:first-child{
border-top:0;
}

.clear{
clear:both;
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
}
```

**The HTML structure is:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a>
        <li><a href="">Drop Down</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">DD Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another One</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Last DD Item</a></li>
            </ul><div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
    </ul><div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**I am using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to show/hide the menu with:**

```
$('#menu ul li').hover(function(){$('ul',this).slideDown(100);},
function(){$('ul',this).slideUp(100);});
```

The code I used is strongly modified, but taken from  [here](https://www.servage.net/blog/2009/03/20/create-a-cool-css-based-drop-down-menu/)

Comment: In case it helps, here are some pure-CSS (no JavaScript) drop-down menus: http://phrogz.net/js/ul2menu/purecss_testsuite.html

Comment: Sorry, the server was down for maintenance. It is up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your dreams are probably safe.** That is, your CSS looks pretty good overall. You may want to consider using Twitter Bootstrap for some of what you're doing (awesome drop-downs), but you can certainly roll-your-own.

To answer your questions:

---

*Should I use* `list-style:none;` *on ULs or LIs (or both)?*

Just on `ul`'s.

---

*Is it better to put* `background-color` *and* `border` *on As or LIs?*

Put them on the `li` elements.

---

*Should the LIs that are inside the absolute floating UL have* `float:left;` *or* `position:relative;`?

These accomplish entirely different things. Floating left should be sufficient, but you may want to do both.

---

You should also refactor your jQuery code, despite the fact that it works:

```
$("#menu ul li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown(100);
  },
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp(100);
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks for the JQuery improvement, and for the other answers. So `floate:none;` is not recommended at all (on the menu>ul>li>ul>li)?

Comment: oh, also Should I use `left:0;` on the absolute positioned UL?